# Zxing cannot be started while StartForeground is running

Tags: xamarin.forms

If you are running Start Foreground from an Android.App service
I get an error when I start Zxing (barcode reading).

```
Error details: Compatible code is not running.
Selective debug execution may or may not be the executable code running in the current thread.
Unhandled Exception:
Java.Lang.NullPointerException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>
```

Is there anyone who can solve this problem?

-- 2020/12/22 add --
Thank you for your reply.

I thought I'd ask a simple question,
It seems that it was not concise but vague Excuse me.

Execute background service to acquire location information continuously (every 15 minutes)
I want to read barcodes as another function,
An error will occur if the barcode is read while the background service is running.

It would be ideal if there was a way to avoid an error in this situation, but I don't know how to deal with it.
Exit background service, read barcode, then
I was wondering if I could handle it by restarting the background service.
I can't solve the problem.

1. Refer to the url below to get the location information in the background.
https://teratail.com/questions/167858

2. Package installation
   ZXing.Net.Mobile (2.4.1)
   ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms (2.4.1)
3. Run the Clicked event on the Xamarin.Forms Button

The code below calls the Zxing form.
await Navigation.PushAsync (new QRScanPage ()); ← * An error occurs here

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
public partial class QRScanPage: ContentPage
{
public Page00_QRScanPage ()
{
InitializeComponent ();
}

```
 void Handle_OnScanResult (ZXing.Result result)
 {
     Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (async () =>
     {
         zxing.IsAnalyzing = false;
         await Navigation.PopAsync ();
         await DisplayAlert ("notification", "Read the following value:" + result.Text, "OK");
         zxing.IsAnalyzing = true;
     });
 }

 protected override void OnAppearing ()
 {
     try
     {
         base.OnAppearing ();
         zxing.IsScanning = true;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {

         DisplayAlert ("ExErr",
             $ "{ex.Message}", Msg.Button.Ok);
     }
 }

 protected override void OnDisappearing ()
 {
     zxing.IsScanning = false;
     base.OnDisappearing ();
 }
```

}

1. Service outage
   Intent serviceIntent = new Intent (this, typeof (BackgroundService)); * "BackgroundService" is the running Service class
   Base.StopService (serviceIntent);
2. Stop with StopSelf () method

As a result, nothing could be solved.

Comment: hi, what part of your code is calling this? what are you trying to achieve? what have you tried to fix the problem?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

2020/12/22: The details of the inquiry have been updated.